# What is Java alternative for .NET's XmlSerializer

Tags: java, c#, xml, porting

I'm porting c# application to Java and don't know what it is doing in details. With what should I replace .Net's XmlSerializer in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: Solved the problem implementing XMLSerializer using DOM + reflection. XStream and don't seem to be the solution.

Comment: Could you explain little bit your approach or link or something that might helpful? I facing same problem. I need to convert XML object that produce from .NET application to java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**XStream**](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream) is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again.

- [Download XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/download.html)
- [XStream - Two Minute Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 5):

[JAXB](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/) is your best bet and its also a Java standard.

**Interesting posts:** (Courtesy of [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan))

- [How does JAXB compare to XStream](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html)
- [How does JAXB compare to Simple](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html)

Comment: does JAXB use XmlSerializer's standard?

Comment: @stiv - JAXB (JSR-222) is a standard that was developed by Sun, Oracle, IBM, SAP, BEA, etc through The Java Community Process (JCP):  http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222.  Some implementations of the standard include:  Metro, EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe.

Comment: @stiv - JAXB is also the standard binding layer for other Java EE standards:  Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS), Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS).  These standards are supported by all Java application servers:  WebLogic, GlassFish, WebSphere, JBoss, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use different technology to serialize/deserialize XML.

From an XML schema :

- There is the standard JaxB : http://jaxb.java.net/
- But I prefer XmlBeans : http://xmlbeans.apache.org/ which is more straightforward IMHO.

With XPath :

- Use the class javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory

Answer (score 0):

[Castor](http://www.castor.org/xml-framework.html) is another simple to use XML data-binding framework for Java.