# Xml Serializer in java

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Java alternative for .NET’s XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107627/what-is-java-alternative-for-nets-xmlserializer)

What does the `XmlSerializer` class exactly do in c# and how can I use the same functionality in java?

The following is just a part of code in c# (is it possible to have this method in java?)

```
public static List<PinglishString> LoadPinglishStrings(string filePath)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ListOfString>));
    TextReader stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.UTF8);
        List<ListOfString> list = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as List<ListOfString> ?? new List<ListOfString>();
        return list;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107627/what-is-java-alternative-for-nets-xmlserializer

Comment: @DanielKelley: very very useful link, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

Example:

```
    // create JAXB context and instantiate marshaller
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    // Write to System.out
    m.marshal(instanceOfSomeClass, System.out);
```

Marshaller --> XMLSerializer

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer: Save List of objects in XML file. 
XmlDeSerializer - does the opposite

I am using this library : [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Comment: thank you so much, i try ed them all, this was the best way

Answer (score 0):

[XmlSerializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents. This enables you to control how objects are encoded into XML.

And for Java found this [xerces-J-API](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.html)